# Change spell check language in WPS Office

Tags: spell-checking, wps-office

I use latest version for Linux (Alpha16 Patch3).

According to [official guide](http://wps-community.org/download/dicts/):

> Installation 
> 1) (from web) Download The Spellcheck Zip Install
>   Package, e.g.: en-US.zip 
> 2) (from WPS) Review --> Set Spellcheck
>   Language --> Install, and choose en-US.zip

But I can't find "Install" button:

[image]

How to change spell check language?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*updated for version 10.1*

The extracted directory from downloaded archive (e.g. en_US, fr_FR, etc) can be put in `/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/dicts` (all users) but also in `~/.kingsoft/office6/dicts` (for each user).

Some dictionaries come with improper names. In each language-folder (e.g. fr_FR) the files have to be renamed so the package of each language has (at least) three files with the following names:

- dict.conf
- main.aff
- main.dic

[image]

Review --> Spell Check --> Set Language --> Set Default

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** Ubuntu 18.04 with WPS 10.1, name and location of the dictionaries was not the decisive factor in my case: the new dictionaries would not appear in the list (under *Review --> Spell Check --> Set Language --> Set Default*) unless they were **first added** under *Review --> Spell Check  --> Spell Check --> Custom dictionaries --> Add*.

[image]

---

[image]

And there added from any location without changing their names - **only then** resulting in them being listed as indicated initially under *Review --> Spell Check --> Set Language --> Set Default*.

[image]

Comment: I have supplementary notes to the previously posted answer:
In my case text correction in WPS Writer only worked after I have copied the file "main.dic" (3,6 MB) from the installation directory into the user directory, and renamed it to "CUSTOM.DIC", so I replaced the existing empty file "CUSTOM.DIC" (0 bytes)
> /opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/dicts/de_DE/main.dic
> /home/*USERNAME*/.kingsoft/office6/data/de_DE/CUSTOM.DIC

Comment: I have edited the answer after testing version 10.1.

Comment: I have updated the answer again.

Comment: https://github.com/wps-community/wps_community_website/tree/master/root/download/dicts

Comment: Note: if spell check is not working at all for you, try an older version. This failed for me: `wps-office_11.1.0.11704`, that worked: `wps-office_10.1.0.6757` (download from [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20181028151445/wps-community.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different issue/variations:
Running Ubuntu 16.04 and installed WPS Office via Snap

(First issue (off-topic) was a complaint about symbol fonts so I had to find and install them.)

With a Snap installation the dictionaries for me are installed under ~/snap/wps-office/1/.kingsoft/office6/dicts

Just don't extract the zip in a way that results in the files being owned by root. WPS Office won't be able to read the files (I learnt the hard way).

It's possible I didn't have to "add custom dictionary"; I can't be sure now, but I've since deleted their entries and I can view and switch my dictionary "Review > Spell Check > Set Language > (Default)" as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use an example using Brazilian Portuguese spell check language.

## In your terminal

First download the required spell check language package...

```
wget http://ifsc2.ifsc.usp.br/utilitarios/WPS-Office/Dicionario%20pt_BR/pt_BR.zip
```

**NOTE:** Many sources state that the language packs are all [here](http://wps-community.org/download/dicts/), but this link does not work (in 2023/09/07). You can try downloading from [here](https://github.com/wachin/wps-office-all-mui-win-language/tree/master/PlayOnLinux%27s%20virtual%20drives/wpsoffice11.2.0.9255wine3.21/drive_c/users/wachin/Local%20Settings/Application%20Data/Kingsoft/WPS%20Office/11.2.0.9255/office6/dicts/spellcheck) too.

Unzip the file to the "spellcheck" folder...

```
sudo unzip pt_BR.zip -d "/usr/lib/office6/dicts/spellcheck/"
```

**IMPORTANT:** The path to the "spellcheck" folder may vary according to the installation method and according to the distribution in use (if not Ubuntu, for example). Then, to find the path use the command `sudo find / -iname "spellcheck" -type d`.

...and give proper permissions...

```
sudo chmod -R 755 "/usr/lib/office6/dicts/spellcheck"
```

.

## In your WPS Writer

Follow "Review" > "Spell Check" > "Set language(C)..."...

[image: Set Spell Check Language]

..., select "Portuguese (Brazil)" and click "Set Default" button.

**Thanks!**

[Ref(s).: https://mateusmuller.me/2017/12/05/alterar-idioma-e-corretor-ortografico-do-wps-office-para-pt-br/ ]

Answer (score 0):

**Update for 11.1.0.11711**

I wanted English spell check, however, my system is set to German locale. Although wps installs en_US by default, English spell-check did't work on my Debian 11 system. I had to:

- Close wps
- Download en_US from [here](https://github.com/HoLuLuLu/wps-office-multilang/tree/master/wps-office-bin/opt/kingsoft/wps-office/office6/dicts/spellcheck/)
- create a folder in the system's language (de_DE in my case) at `~/.local/share/Kingsoft/office6/dicts/de_DE`
- put the three files dict.conf, main.aff and main.dic from github in there.
  Modify dict.conf to distinguish from the "original" English, e.g. `DisplayName=MYEnglish`
- Launch wps and configure "MYEnglish" under Review/Spell Check/Set Language